# How can I optimize a recurrent network in Julia with Flux?

Tags: optimization, neural-network, julia, recurrent-neural-network, flux.jl

I have a recurrent neural network in Flux of the form:

```
net = Chain(LSTM(8,100), Dense(100,1))
```

The input to the network are minute bars of stock data (each of those bars having 8 numbers), where there can be a varying number of bars fed into the recurrent network. I am repeating this on roughly 2000 different stocks. Here is how the data generally looks:

[image]

[image]

I am using the following function to feed the data into the recurrent network:

```
function mapNetworkOverStocks(net, stocksInput)
    unFlattened = map(x -> (output = net.(x); Flux.reset!(net); output), stocksInput)
    map(x -> map(y -> y[1], x), unFlattened)
end
```

and calling it with:

```
mapNetworkOverStocks(net, allStocksData)
```

The problem is that it is running pretty slowly. In Mathematica, I am able to get similar code to run in `7.79389` seconds, while it is taking `93.413394` seconds in Julia. Is there any way to get this running as quickly as the Mathematica version?

Comment: Any reason why you're using a map within a map, just to grab the first index of all elements? Doing stuff like `arr[:,1]` or `arr[1,:]` doesn't require nested maps, I don't think...